# Simple case of MNAR missing data

Tags: binomial-distribution, missing-data, censoring

I believe I have a very simple problem with missing data, but I'm a bit lost because all the materials I read seem to be focused on much more complicated cases.

I have a random variable $X$ which has a Binomial distribution with parameters $n$ and $p$ (i.e., $X\sim B(n,p)$), where $p$ is unknown ($n$ is known). I have $K$ independent samples of $X$, let them be $X_1,\dotsc,X_K$ but some of them are missing, in the sense that I observe the values $R_iX_i$, where $R_i\in\{0,1\}$. I know that $R_i = 0$ when $X_i< C$, for some known constant $C$, otherwise $R_i=1$. This means that my missing data are MNAR (Missing Not At Random), but I know the "mechanism" leading to their being missing, which I believe is what makes my case easier.

Edit: it's a case of left-censoring with Binomial data.

How can I estimate $p$? 
I'm also interested in finding a confidence interval for $p$.

References and links are much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you could call this left-[censoring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Censoring_%28statistics%29). Left-censored *binomial* data is a bit unusual though.

Comment: To clarify, when $X_i < C$ do you observe a zero or a missing value?

Comment: I confirm that this is left-censoring. When $X_i < C$ I observe 0. Question edited to reflect this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can still use maximum likelihood fairly easily without having to resort to the [E-M algorithm](http://www.stat.uiowa.edu/~kcowles/s166_2007/chang166.pdf), which is commonly used for missing data problems.  Just put a wrapper around the binomial distribution so that it calculates $p(x=\text{NA}),\space p(x=C),\space p(x=C+1), \dots$ instead of  $p(x=0),\space p(x=1),\space p(x=2), \dots$ and maximize the likelihood using a univariate maximization routine.

In R, I choose to minimize -2*LL (log likelihood) instead.  The aforementioned "wrapper" is the calculation of `term1` inside the `m2.log.like` function below.

```
# Random generation of data
n <- 25
p <- 0.7
C <- 16
K <- 100
x <- rbinom(K,n,p)
x[x<C] <- NA 

sum(is.na(x))
[1] 19 # 19 of the 100 samples were censored

m2.log.lik <- function(p, n, C, x)
{
  term1 <- sum(dbinom(x[!is.na(x)],n,p,log=TRUE))
  term1 <- term1 + sum(is.na(x)) * log(pbinom(C-1,n,p))
  -2*term1
}

opt.ll <- optimize(m2.log.lik, lower=0.01, upper=0.99, n=n, C=C, x=x)
opt.ll
$minimum
[1] 0.7004906  # Our MLE of p.

$objective
[1] 408.2332
```

To calculate a confidence interval, you can use the asymptotic chi-square distribution of -2*LL and do some root finding to find values for $p$ such that the associated values of -2*LL equal the value associated with the MLE plus some appropriate number based on the chi-square distribution:

```
m2.log.lik.rf <- function(p, n, C, x, tgt)
{
  log.lik(p, n, C, x) - tgt
}

# Calculate a 95% confidence interval
tgt <- m2.log.lik(phat, n, C, x) + qchisq(0.975, 1)  
ub95 <- uniroot(m2.log.lik.rf, lower=phat, upper=phat+0.1, n=n, C=C, x=x, tgt=tgt)
lb95 <- uniroot(m2.log.lik.rf, lower=phat-0.1, upper=phat, n=n, C=C, x=x, tgt=tgt)

lb95$root
[1] 0.6792
ub95$root
[1] 0.721157
```

The sample interval was pretty tight, but then, we did have 100 observations from a binomial(25,0.7), so even with the censoring we should do pretty well.

Comment: why shouldn't he use multiple imputation? Zelig/Amelia in R?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm not very familiar with R. Why did you set the censored data to NA, instead of 0 (which is what I observe)? Also, re: your comment on using E-M: my understanding was that E-M cannot be used when data are NMAR. Is this correct?

Comment: @Matteo - I just set the censored data to NA out of some misplaced sense of purity of numbers in data.  You could use 0 instead; the test in the code would have to be changed appropriately.  In your case, the data is a special type of missing - "censored" - which enables us to ignore the NMAR qualification, as we know (or can deduce easily) the true probability distribution of the observed data.

Comment: @dmk38 - In this case we can construct the exact censored-data likelihood function with ease, enabling MLE, so imputation buys us nothing.